# Heap allocations spike using NSURLSessionDownloadTask to download images in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, instruments, heap-memory, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I am using NSURLSessionDownload tasks to download images in UITableViewCells. Each cell contains an image view and some associated text.

The app must sync with a web service and be able to persist data for when an internet connection is not available. So I am using Core Data to store the textual information and the images are stored in the file system. Most of the images that I have to retrieve at around 10 KB in size. It's only around 20 images in total. One of the images, however, is 6 MB.

Here's my issue: when downloading the 10KB images, the heap allocations's persistent bytes used by the app is around 8 MB. After the 6 MB image has been downloaded, the persistent bytes shoot up to around 100 MB and I get memory warnings and sometimes the app is terminated.

I'm not sure how to remedy this. Any assistance is welcomed. Thanks.

Screen shot of the Leaks Instrument while downloading the smaller sized images.

[image: Leaks Instruments screenshot 1]

Screen shot of the Leaks Instrument once the 6 MB image has been downloaded.

[image: Leaks Instruments screenshot 2]

Here is the code I use to populate the table view cells:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

  Person *person = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.textLabel.text = person.alias;
  cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
  cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", person.status];

  // Determine the path to use to store the file
  NSString *imagePath = [[SyncEngine sharedEngine].imagesDirectory.path stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@", person.alias];

  if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imagePath]) {
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
  } else {
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image-placeholder"];
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:person.imageURL];
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *imageDownloadTask = [[SyncEngine sharedEngine].session downloadTaskWithURL:imageURL completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

  @autoreleasepool {
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location];
    NSLog(@"%@ original image size: %lu B", person.alias, (unsigned long)imageData.length);
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.2);
    NSLog(@"Compressed: %lu", (unsigned long)imageData.length);

    // Save the image to file system
    NSError *saveError = nil;
    BOOL saved = [imageData writeToFile:imagePath options:0 error:&saveError];
    if (saved) {
      NSLog(@"File saved");
    } else {
      NSLog(@"File not saved:\n%@, %@", saveError, saveError.userInfo);
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
    });
  }
}];

    [imageDownloadTask resume];
  }
  return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Just had to compress and resize the images.